# Python getting information from two models in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to access information from two models in my django application here is my models:

```
class Events(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, default='')
    date = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True, default='')
    active = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, default='d')
    seats = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    alcohol_choice = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, default='n')
    starter = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True, default='')
    main_menu = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True, default='')
    dessert = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True, default='')
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True, default='')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'events'

class GalleryImagesEvents(models.Model):

    event = models.ForeignKey(Events, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = ResizedImageField(size=[1200, 800], quality=75, upload_to="events/static/galleryimages")
    file_thumbnail = ResizedImageField(size=[300, 300], crop=['middle', 'center'], upload_to="events/static/galleryimages/thumbnails")
    order = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```

I can have multiple Events for an user, Each event can have multiple gallery images.

What I am trying to do is get all the events from the user and only get one image for the event from the galleryimagesevent model attached to the event.

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def EventsView(request):

    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    events_list_data = Events.objects.filter(user_id=user).order_by('-date')[:10]
    events_list_images = GalleryImagesEvents.objects.filter(event_id=events_list_data)

    return render(request, 'events/view.html', {"events_list_data":events_list_data, 'events_list_images': events_list_images})
```

I know classes are used etc But I am still learning so bare with my coding. :)

Not getting this at all. How to connect them.

```
        {% for event_list in events_list_data %}
            <div class="panel-body event-box">
                <div class="col-md-4 no-padding">
                    <img src="{{ events_list_images.file_thumbnail.url }}" class="img-responsive img-events-thumb">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 event-inner-box">
                    <div>
                        <h4><b>{{ event_list.title }}</b> <span class="event-small">
                            {% if event_list.active == 'r' %} Not approved yet! {% endif %}
                            {% if event_list.active == 'd' %} Approved but deactivated! {% endif %}
                            {% if event_list.active == 'a' %} Approved & Active! {% endif %}
                            {% if event_list.active == 'e' %} Expired! {% endif %}
                        </span></h4>
                        <p>{{ event_list.description|slice:":100" }}...</p>
                        <br>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-small" type="submit">Deactivate</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-small" type="submit">Preview</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-small" type="submit"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 event-inner-box-date">
                    <div>
                        <p></p>
                        <h3><span class="dateShow dateformat_{{ event_list.id }}"></span><br><span class="dayformat_{{ event_list.id }}"></span></h3>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        var dateMonthAsWord = moment('{{ event_list.date }}').format('DD');
                        var dateMonthAsWordMonth = moment('{{ event_list.date }}').format('MMM');
                        $('.dateformat_{{ event_list.id }}').html(dateMonthAsWordMonth);
                        $('.dayformat_{{ event_list.id }}').html(dateMonthAsWord);
                    </script>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Above is how I would like to show my events.

TA!

Comment: do you want to get a random or a (somehow) specific image from the gallery images? You can create a model property for this kind of logic

Comment: Any Random image... Doesn't really matter if I can get a specific image that would be great... say the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `first` template tag to get only one image (first one) from `event_list_data`. or you can use `[0]` index. for example:

```
{% for event_list in events_list_data %}
    <img src="{{events_list.galleryimagesevents_set.all|first.file_thumbnail.url }}">
    <img src="{{events_list.galleryimagesevents_set.all.0.file_thumbnail.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#first

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working from using the above you have provided me:

```
                <div class="col-md-4 no-padding">
                    <img src="{{ event_list.galleryimagesevents_set.all.0.file_thumbnail.url }}" class="img-responsive img-events-thumb">
                </div>
```